# Searching for a ListViewItem within a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

So I have modified my code and what I'm looking for:
I created a jagged array:

```
object[][] arr1 = new object[2][];
```

I add ListViewItems to the array arr1[1] in the following way:

```
ListViewItems x = new ListViewItems(y);
arr1[1][0]= x;
```

Then I need to check if the item x exists within the array

```
if ((arr1[1].Contains(x)))
        {MessageBox.Show("Exists")}
```

Now the problem is it always ends up being false.
 In the array the value are:

arr1[0][0] {Text = "value1"}

the x value is the exact same

```
{Text = "value1"}
```

So I don't now know why it is still being false when I do a Contains() assuming the arr1[1] has about 20 items within it

```
if ((arr1[1].Contains(x)))
    {MessageBox.Show("Exists")}
```

Comment: And I'm guessing your `arr` is actually a list?

Comment: It would be WinForms.

Comment: There _is no need_ to keep a separate array of list outside of the listbox. Your are bound to run into trouble doing this.

Comment: I do this because when I need to delete items from the listView I delete then  based on what is within the array.  I have more than one array's so when I need to delete an Item I reference to a particular array.  This way only what is within the array is deleted.

Comment: @Sach the arr is an array.

Comment: @Reaz, can you edit the question and provided the minimum code needed to show what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm guessing your `arr` is actually a list or an IEnumerable.

So you should probably do,

```
if(arr.Contains(n))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exists");
}
```

Because `Contains()` checks if a collection *contains* something.

If you want to actually compare the zero-th item;

```
if (arr[0] == n)
{
    MessageBox.Show("EXISTS");
}
```

---

**EDIT: *Updated according to OP's updated code/requirements.***

First, what you're creating is **NOT** a two-dimensional array, but an array of arrays. Your `arr` has two elements, and each element is another *array of objects*. Therefore your `arr1[1][0]= x;` assignment doesn't work. What you need to do is assign an array to each element in your first array. Like this:

```
object[][] arr1 = new object[2][];
arr1[0] = new object[1];
arr1[1] = new object[1];
```

*Now* you can set your `x` to that array, like so:

```
arr1[1][0] = x;
```

Secondly, your code sample *still* doesn't work properly. So I'm surprised how you even claim that your code always goes to false condition, because it should thrown an exception because as it is, `arr1[1]` in your `if` condition is `null`. 
Also, there is no such thing as `ListViewItems` class, it's `ListViewItem` class. And we don't know what `y` is in your initialization either. So please learn how to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Since I don't know what `y` is, I used a string and now it works.

```
object[][] arr1 = new object[2][];
arr1[0] = new object[1];
arr1[1] = new object[1];

ListViewItem x = new ListViewItem("value");
arr1[1][0] = x;

if (arr1[1].Contains(x))
    textBox1.Text = "FOUND";
else
    textBox1.Text = "NOT FOUND";
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it.

Comment: Just being curious.  If I decided to use a jagged array instead how would I do the compare?  Lets assume I created a new jagged array: object[][] arr1 = new object[2][]; and the array I need to search is within arr1[1].  How would I compare?

Comment: What do you mean by a jagged array? A two-dimensional array? Well the principle still holds; if you compare two items of the same type you use the comparison operator, `==`. But a true array doesn't have an associated `Contains()` method so you cannot use that unless you write your own.

Comment: Yes a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Within the two-dimensional array I am able to use the .Contains().  I redid my array and created the jagged array now when I use the same as I had above "arr1[0].Contains(n)" it does not find the value of 'n' within the array.

Comment: You need to post your updated code including your arr definition. And what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Update now posted

Comment: @Reaz updated. Hope this helps, and please go through it and from next time on always post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples.